# How to get Word before matching word using regex Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script

I've been trying to extract the value before the match. For example, I have the following sentences:

**Florida 03/22/2022 04/05/2022 Bid Support Help Desk is glad to assist you**

**Florida 04/05/2022 Bid Support Help Desk is glad to assist you**

In these examples, I want to extract anything before the last occurrence of the date. So, the last occurrence of date is: 04/05/2022 and I want to extract

> 03/22/2022
> Florida

because it is behind the matching date. I have been able to get the last occurrence of the date by the following regex:

```
var Date = /(\b[0-9]{2}([\-/ \.])[0-9]{2}[\-/ \.][0-9]{4}\b)(?![A-Z]\1)\b(?!.*\b\2\b)/gs.exec(String)[0];
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: you have this `Florida 03/22/2022 04/05/2022 Bid Support Help Desk is glad to assist you` string but you want to extract florida & are both dates are random?

Comment: Maybe you want `/(\S+)\s+\b(\d{2}([-/ .])\d{2}\3\d{4})\b(?!.*\b\d{2}([-/ .])\d{2}\4\d{4}\b)/`? See https://regex101.com/r/LK9nXX/1

Comment: Yes, the above regex is working just as I need, but can we exclude the last occurrence from the result because it gives the following matches for both examples:

**03/22/2022 04/05/2022**
and 
**Florida 04/05/2022**

Comment: Could you please edit the question and explain what your problem is? Do you want to say you need 1) `03/22/2022` and 2) `Florida` from the two strings you mentioned? Note you already have them in Group 1. Or do you want to get no results for String 2?

Comment: Your proposed regex gave the following matches:
**03/22/2022 04/05/202** and
**Florida 04/05/2022**

I just want  **03/22/2022** and  **Florida** by excluding the date (04/05/2022)

Comment: That does not matter what is matched. You just need Group 1 value. Of course, you can also use a lookahead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
\S+(?=\s+\b(\d{2}([-/ .])\d{2}\2\d{4})\b(?!.*\b\d{2}([-/ .])\d{2}\3\d{4}\b))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LK9nXX/2). *Details*:

- `\S+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(?=` - a positive lookahead that requires the following patterns to match immediately to the right of the current location:
- `\s+`   one or more whitespaces
- `\b(\d{2}([-/ .])\d{2}\2\d{4})\b` - Group1: word boundary, two digits, a separator (captured in Group 2), two digits, the same separator char as in Group 2, four digits, word boundary
- `(?!.*\b\d{2}([-/ .])\d{2}\3\d{4}\b)` - a negative lookahead failing the match if there are zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible followed with word boundary, two digits, a separator (captured in Group 3), two digits, the same separator char as in Group 3, four digits, word boundary
- `)` - end of the positive lookahead.

```js
const texts = ['Florida 03/22/2022 04/05/2022 Bid Support Help Desk is glad to assist you','Florida 04/05/2022 Bid Support Help Desk is glad to assist you'];
const reg = /\S+(?=\s+\b(\d{2}([-/ .])\d{2}\2\d{4})\b(?!.*\b\d{2}([-/ .])\d{2}\3\d{4}\b))/;
for (const text of texts) {
  console.log(text, '=>', text.match(reg)?.[0]);
}
```